# Spark: understanding the DAG and forcing transformations

Tags: scala, caching, apache-spark

Hello stackoverflow community.

I ask your help in understanding if my thoughts are correct or I'm missing some points in my Spark job.

I currently have two rdds that I want to subtract.
Both the rdds are built as different transformations on the same father RDD.

First of all, the father RDD is cached after it is obtained:

```
val fatherRdd = grandFather.repartition(n).mapPartitions(mapping).cache
```

Then the two rdds are transformed.
One is (pseudocode):

```
son1= rddFather.filter(filtering_logic).map(take_only_key).distinct
```

The other one is :

```
son2= rddFather.filter(filtering_logic2).map(take_only_key).distinct
```

The two sons are then subtracted to obtain only the keys in son1:

```
son1.subtract(son2)
```

I would expect the squence of the transformations to be the following:

1. mapPartitions
2. repartition
3. caching

Then, starting from cached data, map filter map distinct on both rdds and then subtracting.

This is not happening, what I see are the two `distinct` operations running in parallel, apparently not exploiting the benefits of caching (there are no skipped tasks), and taking almost the same computation time.
Below the image of the dag taken from spark ui.
[image]

Do you have any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct in your observations. Transformations on RDDs are lazy, so caching will happen after the first time the RDD is actually computed.

If you call an action on your parent RDD, it should be computed and cached. Then your subsequent operations will operate on the cached data.

Comment: Thank you very much. I probably missed the documentation part saying:
"You can mark an RDD to be persisted using the persist() or cache() methods on it. The first time it is computed in an action, it will be kept in memory on the nodes."
Since i thought that `cache` would perform an action to effectively cache everything.
My spark job is now much faster and also better in terms of resource allocation.

Comment: PS. I added a count().